# Is there a swifty way to write "if case" for an enum with an associated value

Tags: swift, enums

I have a computed property on an enum.

```
  var hasResults: Bool {
     if case .hasResults(_) = self {
        return true
     }
     return false
  }
```

I want to make it swifty and inline.  I want to do something like this:

```
  var hasResults: Bool {
     return case .hasResults(_) = self
  }
```

Alas, the compiler won't allow it.

**Is there a swifty inline way to write the same statement?**

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a swifty inline way to write the same statement?

No, there is not.

**You can do only smth like that.**

```swift
    var hasResults: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .hasResult: return true
        default: return false
        }
    }
```

you *could* use `var hasResults: Bool { return self == .noResult }` only if your enum type didn't have AssociatedValue